# How can I create a table?

Tags: c++

I have an assignment to write a .txt file using inputs from the codes i made from c++, i wanted to make a table and the easiest solution is using ncurses.
I was taught to use fstream but I don't know how to use fstream to take the output from ncurses

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and [mre]. Your question is far from being precise enough to understand what you *really* want to do, please add more details and preferrably the code you have written so far.

Comment: `ncurses` doesn't sound like an optimal way to write a text file... AFAIK it is normally used for sending control codes to a terminal to control the cursor position.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Looks to me as if she/he wants to manipulate console with ncurses and/or retrieve the data to be written to file then. Still the question is pretty unclear...

Comment: Sorry for the bad wording, i'm not a native speaker and my knowledge on programming is very limited so i didn't know how to make the question more specific. @Aconcagua is correct, I was trying to ask if i could get the output from the ncurses terminal to be written on a .txt file.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need ncurses to make a table. As a hint, take a look at the [std::setw](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) and [std::right](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) iostream manipulators. They define the minimum amount of space a field should take when printed and the alignment within that space, respectively.

As a simple example, let's print a table:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::right;
using std::setw;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

int main() {
    vector<vector<string>> data = {
        { "Homer", "Simpson", "42" },
        { "Marge", "Simpson", "35" },
        { "Bart", "Simpson", "10" },
        { "Lisa", "Simpson", "9" },
        { "Maggie", "Simpson", "2" },
        { "Ned", "Flanders", "40" },
    };

    for (auto& row : data) {
        cout << setw(10) << row[0] << setw(10) << row[1] << setw(5) << row[2] << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
     Homer   Simpson   42
     Marge   Simpson   35
      Bart   Simpson   10
      Lisa   Simpson    9
    Maggie   Simpson    2
       Ned  Flanders   40
```

Comment: Nice guess. Not sure if that's what user is after, though (*'I have an assignment to write a .txt file'* – maybe modified title even is inapproprate?). I could imagine that ncurses should have been used to let *user* modify the table contents, but that's just another assumption...